# How to delete folder into recycle bin

Tags: c++, windows, directory, recycle-bin

I am programing under C++, MFC, windows.

I want to delete a folder into recycle bin.
How can I do this?

```
    CString filePath = directorytoBeDeletePath;
    TCHAR ToBuf[MAX_PATH + 10];
    TCHAR FromBuf[MAX_PATH + 10];
    ZeroMemory(ToBuf, sizeof(ToBuf));
    ZeroMemory(FromBuf, sizeof(FromBuf));

    lstrcpy(FromBuf, filePath);

    SHFILEOPSTRUCT FileOp;
    FileOp.hwnd = NULL
    FileOp.wFunc=FO_DELETE; 
    FileOp.pFrom=FromBuf;
    FileOp.pTo = NULL;
    FileOp.fFlags=FOF_ALLOWUNDO|FOF_NOCONFIRMATION;
    FileOp.hNameMappings=NULL;
    bRet=SHFileOperation(&FileOp);
```

Any thing wrong with the code above?
It always failed.

I found the problem:
filePath  should be : "c:\abc" not "c:\abc\"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return value from SHFileOperation is an int, and should specify the error code. What do you get?

Answer (score 0):

i know it is not the right way but if you cant find a solution you can try this..

download file nircmd.exe or another exe that can empty recycle bin.

then you call these functions by system("nircmd.exe emptybin")

Answer (score 0):

You have found a solution that works, however it's only by accident.  The actual problem here is that the `pFrom` parameter is in a special format. According to the MSDN docs for [SHFILEOPTS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/desktop/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-_shfileopstructa), it stores a list of file paths, each one null-terminated, and an extra null after the last one.

In your case this happens to work because the `FromBuf` array is longer than the filename and all the entries are initialised to zero. The more general solution is to create a buffer that is long enough for the filename and then add two nul characters after it.  Note that Windows filenames *can* be longer than `_MAX_PATH`, eg see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/fileio/naming-a-file#maximum-path-length-limitation